# How to wait for tekton pipelinRun conditions

Tags: kubernetes, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have the following code within a gitlab pipeline which results in some kind of race condition:

```sh
kubectl apply -f pipelineRun.yaml
tkn pipelinerun logs -f pipeline-run
```

The `tkn` command immediately exits, since the pipelineRun object is not yet created. There is one very nice solution for this problem:

```sh
kubectl apply -f pipelineRun.yaml
kubectl wait --for=condition=Running --timeout=60s pipelinerun/pipeline-run
tkn pipelinerun logs -f pipeline-run
```

Unfortunately this is not working as expected, since `Running` seems to be no valid *condition* for a pipelineRun object. So my question is: what are the valid *conditions* of a pipelineRun object?

Comment: Did you try with --for=condition=Ready ?

Comment: I think "creating" is one of them as well

Answer (score 0):

I didn't search too far and wide, but it looks like they only have two condition types imported from the knative.dev project?

https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/vendor/knative.dev/pkg/apis/condition_types.go#L32

The link above is for the imported condition types from the pipeline source code of which it looks like Tekton only uses "Ready" and "Succeeded".

```golang
const (
    // ConditionReady specifies that the resource is ready.
    // For long-running resources.
    ConditionReady ConditionType = "Ready"
    // ConditionSucceeded specifies that the resource has finished.
    // For resource which run to completion.
    ConditionSucceeded ConditionType = "Succeeded"
)
```

But there may be other imports of this nature elsewhere in the project.

Comment: This is a question and a link. How do you intend this to answer the question at the top of this page?

Comment: The question is intended to imply, "maybe there are more?" and the link is intended to be a definite answer to the question.  As in, "This is an answer".

Comment: So the question is not meant rhetoric, answering in itself. Then your posts only answers via link, making it link-only, which in turn is not considered an answer on StackOverflow. Please at least summarise the actual answer, instead of only linking.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Didn't know that link only answers were verboten.

Comment: Thanks for augmenting the link. However, I still do not get how this is supposed to answer the question or solve the problem. Do you need a [mred] to track down the problem completly?

Comment: q: "what are the valid conditions of a pipelineRun object?" a: 'it looks like Tekton only uses "Ready" and "Succeeded".'  am I missing something?  what is an 'mred'?

Comment: Sorry. mred is a typo should be mre which should have caused the link [mre].

Comment: added the code block in reference.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tekton `TaskRuns` and `PipelineRun` only use a condition of type `Succeeded`.

Example:

```yaml
conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-05-04T02:19:14Z"
    message: "Tasks Completed: 4, Skipped: 0"
    reason: Succeeded
    status: "True"
    type: Succeeded
```

The different status and messages available for the `Succeeded` condition are available in the documentation:

- `TaskRun`: https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/taskruns/#monitoring-execution-status
- `PipelineRun`: https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelineruns/#monitoring-execution-status

As a side note, there is an [activity timeout](https://github.com/tektoncd/cli/commit/52228c24dca54486c41dc10a1d137aac4e66d0c5) available in the API. That timeout is not surfaced to the CLI options though. You could create a [tkn feature request](https://github.com/tektoncd/cli/issues) for that.